# how to use the vision_opencv on python script?

Tags: ros, python, vision-opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

i want to use the vision_script on python script.

can you show me the example?

and how configurate the cmakelist.txt?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208900/how-to-use-the-vision_opencv-on-python-script?/) by [anthuny shin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22384/anthuny-shin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For Python you don't really need to configure CMakeLists.txt

You could just use opencv directly in Python by including it as follows:

```
import cv2
```

Then use all opencv algorithms accessible under the namespace cv2 (cv2.imshow() for example). You should of course have opencv installed on your computer.

For converting between OpenCV image format and ROS images check [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython)

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2015-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anthuny shin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22384/anthuny-shin/) on 2015-05-10**:
I add 'import opencv2 as cv2', but is not work. it's occur the error ' no module named opencv2.

how to solve?

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-05-12**:
Sorry my mistake, I edited the code. Normally all should work fine if you installed opencv from the debs using sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev